# How to add a checkbox to a panel header?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, panel

I'm trying to find out how to add a checkbox to a panel header so panel can be deacivated (as well as storing that checkbox value in some property). It may be quite obious task, but I didn't find any info about it in the docs so far.

Example of what I'm trying to achive is the "Gravity" panel, that can be turned off with the checkbox.

[image: Example of what i'm trying to achive]

Any suggestions or leads? I would be grateful for any code examples with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add [`draw_header(context)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Panel.html?highlight=draw_header#bpy.types.Panel.draw_header) function to your `Panel` class and supply any `bool` property. Following example is based on `ui_panel_simple.py` template:

```
import bpy

class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "object"

    def draw_header(self,context):
        # Example property to display a checkbox, can be anything
        self.layout.prop(context.scene.render, "use_border", text="")
    
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.label(text="Hello world!", icon='WORLD_DATA')


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldPanel)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(HelloWorldPanel)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Answer (score 3):

**Adding to already registered panels**

As an extra to other answers re defining a draw header on a new panel class, can monkey around with existing panel classes.

Here is an example that adds gravity checkbox and "XXX" to audio panel header, and disables that panels `layout` with `scene.use_gravity` (*silly*)

[image]

```
import bpy
from bl_ui.properties_scene import SCENE_PT_audio

dr = SCENE_PT_audio.draw

def draw(self, context):
    scene = context.scene
    layout = self.layout
    layout.enabled = scene.use_gravity
    dr(self, context)

def draw_header(self, context):
    scene = context.scene
    self.layout.prop(scene, "use_gravity", text="XXX")

if SCENE_PT_audio.is_registered:    
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SCENE_PT_audio) 
SCENE_PT_audio.draw = draw   
SCENE_PT_audio.draw_header = draw_header
bpy.utils.register_class(SCENE_PT_audio)
```