# How can I add a panel to the properties area of the file browser?

Tags: python, scripting, operator, panel, file-browser

I would like to wrap my properties inside collapsible panels when using the `ExportHelper` or `ImportHelper` class but I can not figure it out how to draw them properly:

[image]

This is my code so far (reduced version of the *Operator File Export* template):

```
import bpy

# ExportHelper is a helper class, defines filename and
# invoke() function which calls the file selector.
from bpy_extras.io_utils import ExportHelper
from bpy.props import StringProperty, BoolProperty, EnumProperty
from bpy.types import Operator


class ExportSomeData(Operator, ExportHelper):
    """This appears in the tooltip of the operator and in the generated docs"""
    bl_idname = "export_test.some_data"  # important since its how bpy.ops.import_test.some_data is constructed
    bl_label = "Export Some Data"

    # ExportHelper mixin class uses this
    filename_ext = ".txt"

    def execute(self, context):
        return {'FINISHED'}


class SubPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = 'SubPanel'
    bl_idname = 'Sub_PT_Layout'
    bl_parent_id = 'export_test.some_data'
    bl_space_type = 'FILE_BROWSER'
    bl_region_type = 'TOOL_PROPS'

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.label(text = 'test')

        use_setting: BoolProperty(
            name="Example Boolean",
            description="Example Tooltip",
            default=True,
        )


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ExportSomeData)
    bpy.utils.register_class(SubPanel)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SubPanel)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ExportSomeData)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    bpy.ops.export_test.some_data('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

Unfortunately I get the following error:

> RuntimeError: Error: Registering panel class: parent 'export_test.some_data' for 'Sub_PT_Layout' not found

**Q:** How can I add a panel to the properties area of the file browser when using the `ExportHelper` or `ImportHelper` class?

Comment: As the error mentions your parent ID name is incorrect. You need to use the class name not the `bl_idname` also you are trying to parent a panel to an operator instead of another panel. I believe the panel you are looking for is `bl_parent_id = 'FILE_PT_operator'` however your test call will only include your defined operator not the full panel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would have to add a `draw()` method along with a `pass` statement to the operator in order to skip drawing and declare a `Panel` class, get the actual operator from that class in order to draw it's properties. Demo based on the *Operator Export* template that comes with Blender:

[image]

```
import bpy

# ExportHelper is a helper class, defines filename and
# invoke() function which calls the file selector.
from bpy_extras.io_utils import ExportHelper
from bpy.props import StringProperty, BoolProperty, EnumProperty
from bpy.types import Operator, Panel


class ExportSomeData(Operator, ExportHelper):
    """This appears in the tooltip of the operator and in the generated docs"""
    bl_idname = "export_test.some_data"  # important since its how bpy.ops.import_test.some_data is constructed
    bl_label = "Export Some Data"

    # ExportHelper mixin class uses this
    filename_ext = ".txt"

    filter_glob: StringProperty(
        default="*.txt",
        options={'HIDDEN'},
        maxlen=255,  # Max internal buffer length, longer would be clamped.
    )

    # List of operator properties, the attributes will be assigned
    # to the class instance from the operator settings before calling.
    use_setting: BoolProperty(
        name="Example Boolean",
        description="Example Tooltip",
        default=True,
    )

    type: EnumProperty(
        name="Example Enum",
        description="Choose between two items",
        items=(
            ('OPT_A', "First Option", "Description one"),
            ('OPT_B', "Second Option", "Description two"),
        ),
        default='OPT_A',
    )

    def execute(self, context):
        return {'FINISHED'}
    
    def draw(self, context):
        pass


class CUSTOM_PT_export_settings(Panel):
    bl_space_type = 'FILE_BROWSER'
    bl_region_type = 'TOOL_PROPS'
    bl_label = "Settings Panel"
    bl_options = {'DEFAULT_CLOSED'}

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        sfile = context.space_data
        operator = sfile.active_operator
        return operator.bl_idname == "EXPORT_TEST_OT_some_data"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.use_property_split = True
        layout.use_property_decorate = False  # No animation.

        sfile = context.space_data
        operator = sfile.active_operator

        layout.prop(operator, 'type')
        layout.prop(operator, 'use_setting')
        

# Only needed if you want to add into a dynamic menu
def menu_func_export(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(ExportSomeData.bl_idname, text="Text Export Operator")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ExportSomeData)
    bpy.utils.register_class(CUSTOM_PT_export_settings)
    bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_file_export.append(menu_func_export)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(CUSTOM_PT_export_settings)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ExportSomeData)
    bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_file_export.remove(menu_func_export)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    bpy.ops.export_test.some_data('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

Make sure to add a `poll()` method to the panel, testing for the actual `bl_idname` of the operator otherwise the panel will appear for all other export operators as well.

```
@classmethod
def poll(cls, context):
    sfile = context.space_data
    operator = sfile.active_operator
    return operator.bl_idname == "EXPORT_TEST_OT_some_data"
```

Note: Once the export operator is registered you can use the python console and call its `idname()` method getting the proper `bl_idname`:

```
>>> bpy.ops.export_test.some_data.idname()
'EXPORT_TEST_OT_some_data'
```

---

Just for the sake, adding *sub panels* is possible as well:

[image]

```
import bpy

# ExportHelper is a helper class, defines filename and
# invoke() function which calls the file selector.
from bpy_extras.io_utils import ExportHelper
from bpy.props import StringProperty, BoolProperty, EnumProperty
from bpy.types import Operator, Panel


class ExportSomeData(Operator, ExportHelper):
    """This appears in the tooltip of the operator and in the generated docs"""
    bl_idname = "export_test.some_data"  # important since its how bpy.ops.import_test.some_data is constructed
    bl_label = "Export Some Data"
    bl_options = {'PRESET', 'UNDO'}

    # ExportHelper mixin class uses this
    filename_ext = ".txt"

    filter_glob: StringProperty(
        default="*.txt",
        options={'HIDDEN'},
        maxlen=255,  # Max internal buffer length, longer would be clamped.
    )

    # List of operator properties, the attributes will be assigned
    # to the class instance from the operator settings before calling.
    use_setting: BoolProperty(
        name="Example Boolean",
        description="Example Tooltip",
        default=True,
    )

    type: EnumProperty(
        name="Example Enum",
        description="Choose between two items",
        items=(
            ('OPT_A', "First Option", "Description one"),
            ('OPT_B', "Second Option", "Description two"),
        ),
        default='OPT_A',
    )

    def execute(self, context):
        return {'FINISHED'}
    
    def draw(self, context):
        self.layout.label(text="Hello World")
        #self.layout.prop(self, 'type')
        #pass


class EXAMPLE_PT_panel_1(Panel):
    bl_space_type = 'FILE_BROWSER'
    bl_region_type = 'TOOL_PROPS'
    bl_label = "Settings Panel 1"
    #bl_parent_id = "FILE_PT_operator" # Optional

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        sfile = context.space_data
        operator = sfile.active_operator
        return operator.bl_idname == "EXPORT_TEST_OT_some_data"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        sfile = context.space_data
        operator = sfile.active_operator
        
        layout.label(text="This is the first Panel")
        layout.prop(operator, 'type')
        layout.prop(operator, 'use_setting')


class EXAMPLE_PT_panel_2(Panel):
    bl_space_type = 'FILE_BROWSER'
    bl_region_type = 'TOOL_PROPS'
    bl_label = "Settings Panel 2"
    bl_parent_id = "EXAMPLE_PT_panel_1"
    bl_options = {'DEFAULT_CLOSED'}

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        sfile = context.space_data
        operator = sfile.active_operator
        return operator.bl_idname == "EXPORT_TEST_OT_some_data"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        
        sfile = context.space_data
        operator = sfile.active_operator
        
        layout.label(text="This is the second Panel")
        layout.prop(operator, 'type')


# Only needed if you want to add into a dynamic menu
def menu_func_export(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(ExportSomeData.bl_idname, text="Text Export Operator")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ExportSomeData)
    bpy.utils.register_class(EXAMPLE_PT_panel_1)
    bpy.utils.register_class(EXAMPLE_PT_panel_2)
    bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_file_export.append(menu_func_export)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(EXAMPLE_PT_panel_2)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(EXAMPLE_PT_panel_1)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ExportSomeData)
    bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_file_export.remove(menu_func_export)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    bpy.ops.export_test.some_data('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

Related: [How do a create a foldout UI panel?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/155515/how-do-a-create-a-foldout-ui-panel/155517#155517)

---

If you'd like to add a checkbox to one of the panel headers, declare a `BoolProperty` in your operator (alternatively use the scope of the window manager):

```
class ExportSomeData(Operator, ExportHelper):
    ...
    bake = BoolProperty(default=False)
    ...
```

And call `Layout.prop()` in the dedicated `draw_header()` method of the panel:

```
def draw_header(self, context):
    sfile = context.space_data
    operator = sfile.active_operator

    self.layout.prop(operator, "bake", text="")
```

Related: [How to add a checkbox to a panel header?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/147054/how-to-add-a-checkbox-to-a-panel-header)

Comment: I just saw, this adds the "Settings Panel" to my own custom file browser AND to the standard one when you click File>Export>glTF 2.0 (.glb/gltf)

Comment: How do you make a panel with a checkbox in it? Like the Bake Animation panel in the questions screenshot

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/147054/how-to-add-a-checkbox-to-a-panel-header @Lala_Ghost

Comment: But how do you access the state of the checkbox in the different panel class?

Comment: Add a bool property to the operator, window manager or whatever @Lala_Ghost