# Get checkbox state from sub panel

Tags: panel, file-browser

I am trying get the state of the checkbox in my animation subpanel and would like to set myBool to it's state.

Here is my code:

```
import bpy
import os
from bpy_extras.io_utils import ExportHelper
from bpy.props import (StringProperty, CollectionProperty, BoolProperty, EnumProperty)
from bpy.types import (Operator, OperatorFileListElement,)
import textwrap


class WorldOriginExport(Operator, ExportHelper):
    bl_label = 'Export'
    bl_idname = 'object.world_origin_export'
    bl_description = textwrap.fill('Moves each selected object to the worlds origin and exports them as a gltf separate', 80)
    bl_options = {'PRESET', 'UNDO', 'REGISTER'}
    files = CollectionProperty(name = 'File Path', type = OperatorFileListElement,)
    directory = StringProperty(subtype = 'DIR_PATH',)
    filename_ext = '.gltf'

    myBool = False

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        sfile = context.space_data
        operator = sfile.active_operator
        return operator.bl_idname == 'OBJECT_OT_world_origin_export'


    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.use_property_split = False
        layout.use_property_decorate = False  # No animation.

        sfile = context.space_data
        operator = sfile.active_operator


    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.ops.export_scene.gltf(filepath = folder_path + os.sep + sel.name)
        return {'FINISHED'}



class GltfSeparate_PT_Panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_space_type = 'FILE_BROWSER'
    bl_region_type = 'TOOL_PROPS'
    bl_label = 'glTF Separate'
    bl_options = {'DEFAULT_CLOSED'}


    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        sfile = context.space_data
        operator = sfile.active_operator
        return operator.bl_idname == 'OBJECT_OT_world_origin_export'


    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.use_property_split = True
        layout.use_property_decorate = False  # No animation.



class GltfSeparateAnimation_PT_Panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_space_type = 'FILE_BROWSER'
    bl_region_type = 'TOOL_PROPS'
    bl_label = 'Animation1'
    bl_parent_id = 'GltfSeparate_PT_Panel'
    bl_options = {'DEFAULT_CLOSED'}


    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        sfile = context.space_data
        operator = sfile.active_operator
        return operator.bl_idname == 'OBJECT_OT_world_origin_export'


    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.use_property_split = True
        layout.use_property_decorate = False  # No animation.



class GltfSeparateAnimationAnimation_PT_Panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_space_type = 'FILE_BROWSER'
    bl_region_type = 'TOOL_PROPS'
    bl_label = ''
    bl_parent_id = 'GltfSeparateAnimation_PT_Panel'
    bl_options = {'DEFAULT_CLOSED'}


    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        sfile = context.space_data
        operator = sfile.active_operator
        return operator.bl_idname == 'OBJECT_OT_world_origin_export'


    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.use_property_split = True
        layout.use_property_decorate = False  # No animation.


    def draw_header(self, context):
        scene = context.scene
        self.layout.prop(scene, "use_gravity", text = 'Animation2')



def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(WorldOriginExport)
    bpy.utils.register_class(GltfSeparate_PT_Panel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(GltfSeparateAnimation_PT_Panel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(GltfSeparateAnimationAnimation_PT_Panel)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(GltfSeparateAnimationAnimation_PT_Panel)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(GltfSeparateAnimation_PT_Panel)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(GltfSeparate_PT_Panel)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(WorldOriginExport)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    register()
    bpy.ops.object.world_origin_export('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

Comment: My explanation was too compressed? Didn't you see [my edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/217792/how-can-i-add-a-panel-to-the-properties-area-of-the-file-browser/217796#217796)? TLDR; To get a checkbox you'd have to declare a property rather then a regular python variable and then get a reference to active operator (in your case) to get the actual value from: https://pasteall.org/0ZJi You're welcome.

Comment: Yeah, I could not do much with the short answer since I am quite new to Python in Blender
The second link helped a bit but did not solved it
I will look into it tomorrow
Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Click the [pasteall link](https://pasteall.org/0ZJi/raw) in my first comment, copy paste, done.